# From column format to multi column format in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, string-formatting, vba

I have .txt data with block-format :

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

In this example I have 3 blocks of size 2. The size does not vary with blocks, it is fixed. My real life case has around 500 block of size 500. I would like to import such data in Excel with format

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

that is each column represent a block. I was searching for an online tool that would provide simple a simple copy-to-clipboard tool for that but I did not find any. How would you do this in Excel VBA given the range of my column and the size of the blocks (here range A1:A6 and block size 2) ?

Comment: have you tried using formulas?  That's a pretty small dataset so should be easy to do.  There's no import option I'm aware of that can do the rearrangment automatically.

Comment: I chose that example for the sake of clarity. My real life case has 500 blocks of size 500.

Comment: can you give me the code to read the txt file? Cause i want provide answer to you by your effort

Comment: That's quite a different scenario from your original post. Maybe you could update your question to clarify your exact needs. It's not clear (for example) what a "block of size 500" represents (500x500? 500 cells?) How are the blocks separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()
    ReadBlocks "C:\local files\tmp.txt", 100, ActiveSheet.Range("a1")
End Sub


Sub ReadBlocks(sPath As String, BlockSize As Long, rngDest As Range)

    Dim fso As Object, f As Object, val, r As Long, c As Long

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set f = fso.opentextfile(sPath, 1) '1=forReading

    r = 0
    c = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
        rngDest.Offset(r, c).Value = f.ReadLine
        If (r + 1) Mod BlockSize = 0 Then
            r = 0
            c = c + 1
        Else
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Loop

haveError:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: For 500 x 500, it shouldn't matter much, but I usually load it into an array and paste to Excel once.